# "Cried his father in transports"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "in transports" mean in the [cherry tree story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_Locke_Weems#Cherry-tree_anecdote) from *The Life of George Washington* by Mason Locke Weems:

> "Run to my arms, you dearest boy," cried his father **in transports**, "run to my arms; glad am I, George, that you killed my tree; for you have paid me for it a thousand fold. Such an act of heroism in my son is more worth than a thousand trees, though blossomed with silver, and their fruits of purest gold."

https://books.google.ca/books?id=jnZGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=inauthor:%22Mason+Locke+Weems%22+%22in+transports%22

Comment: As an aside I wonder whether 'Lewis Carroll' was parodying this passage when he wrote "Come to my arms my blemish boy" in Jabberwocky. He probably knew the Weems book and it sounds like Dodgson's sense of humour to me.

Comment: "... his father cried [out] in transports [of delight]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking dictionaries sometimes helps.

> **transport** NOUN
>   2 (usually transports).  An overwhelmingly strong emotion.
>   ‘art can send people into transports of delight’
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transport)